# It is possible to update a Live USB with persistent installed?

Tags: system-installation, live-environment

So i have a Live Ubuntu 14.04,installed on an USB 2.0 8 GB Flash Drive,i've created 2 partition first around 1 GB for the extracted Ubuntu ISO and the rest is a partition labeled `casper-rw` for persistent and formatted as Ext4.The question is,Could i update it in usual way like updating  Ubuntu that installed in usual way (e.g. Installed in Desktop or Laptop HDD).Is it possible ?

P.S. : I've tried to do that with usual Live Ubuntu 13.10 with persistent installed but the terminal show some error and when i reboot the Live Ubuntu,it won't start at all.Just a dark screen with something white blinking :v

Comment: Persistence will use up more and more data, even if you delete things. It's not a viable option.

Comment: The same happens to me, both with casper-rw file or partition, I tried also Lubuntu, same issue; at 1st system update (on brand new USB live system), the update gives an error and then the USB won't boot.

Answer (score 2):

Persistent has problem of a late, so I wouldn't use it for "persistent" installations anymore. I would install the whole thing in the USB memory as [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator).

Comment: @OP: Be aware, that you will need a FAST pendrive for this. I used generic (Kingston DT2, some Sandisk one, etc) drives, and it took like 5-7 hours to upgrade my install. And well, every single write was a pain. So use a fast drive.

Comment: So it's possible to Install whole environment to a pendrive,but isn't it take more space than using persistent ? and i'm sure installing on a pendrive will worn out the USB faster than using a persistent,am i correct ?

Comment: @TommyAriaPradana the drive will take the same space using persistence or not. And writing to the drive has nothing to do with persistence, the writes will be the same.